# Difficulty writing a Bmp file in C++ manually (using Xcode)

Tags: c++, image, bmp

I'm currently trying to create a ray tracer in C++ but I'm having difficulty writing the .bmp produced at the end. I'm determined to do it manually, so I can learn more about image files and writing them etc. But I'm having some difficulty. I'm fairly new to C++ but have been using Python for a while.

I'm almost there now, I just have one strange problem. Everything is correct up to mid way trough the important colours (which I set to 0), where all sorts of random characters spring up and this continues for the next few bytes, a couple of bytes in to the pixel data. Before and after that everything is fine, but I just can't explain it. My current code is in the edit:

Here is the hex:

[image: http://yfrog.com/j3picture1equp]

the problem area is highlighted

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
//-------------------------Object list
const int renderSize[2] = {254,254};
float sphere1Pos[3] = {0.0,0.0,0.0}; //first sphere at origin to make calculations easier
float sphere1Radius = 10.0;
float sphere1Colour= (255.0,0.0,0.0); 
float light1Pos = (0.0,20.0,0.0); //Above sphere
float light1Intensity = 0.5;
// ------------------------



float dot(float* a,float* b); //Calculates the dot product

struct pixel {

    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
    };

//bmp--------------
struct bitmapMagicNumber {
    unsigned char magicNumber[2];
    };

struct bitmapFileHeader {
    unsigned char fileSize;
    short reserved1;
    long reserved2;
    short offset;
    };

struct bitmapInformationHeader {
    short headerSize;
    short padding;
    short width;
    short height; 
    short planes;
    short bitDepth;
    short compression;
    short imageSize;
    short xPixelsPerMetre;
    short yPixelsPerMetre;
    short colours;
    short importantColours;
    };

void setBitmapMagicNumber(bitmapMagicNumber& magicNum){
    magicNum.magicNumber[0] = 0x42;
    magicNum.magicNumber[1] = 0x4D;
    };

void setBitmapFileHeader(bitmapFileHeader& fileHeader,bitmapInformationHeader& informationHeader,pixel pixelArray) {
    fileHeader.fileSize = 54 + sizeof(pixelArray);
    fileHeader.reserved1 = 0;
    fileHeader.reserved2 = 0;
    fileHeader.offset = 54;
    };

void setBitmapInformationHeader(bitmapInformationHeader& informationHeader){
    informationHeader.headerSize = 40;
    informationHeader.padding=0;
    informationHeader.width = renderSize[0];
    informationHeader.height = renderSize[1];
    informationHeader.planes = 1;
    informationHeader.bitDepth = 24;
    informationHeader.compression = 0;
    informationHeader.imageSize = 0;
    informationHeader.xPixelsPerMetre = 0;
    informationHeader.yPixelsPerMetre = 0 ;
    informationHeader.colours = 0;
    informationHeader.importantColours = 0;
    };

void writeBitmap(bitmapMagicNumber& magicNum, bitmapFileHeader& fileHeader,bitmapInformationHeader& informationHeader,pixel pixelArray){
    ofstream out("test.bmp",ios::out|ios::binary);

    //file header
    out.write((char*) &magicNum,2);
    out.write((char*) &fileHeader.fileSize,sizeof(fileHeader.fileSize));
    if (sizeof(fileHeader.fileSize)<3){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
    out.write((char*) &fileHeader.reserved1,2);
    out.write((char*) &fileHeader.reserved2,2);
    out.write((char*) &fileHeader.offset,sizeof(fileHeader.offset));
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);


    //information header
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.headerSize,sizeof(informationHeader.headerSize));
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);



    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.width,sizeof(informationHeader.width));
    if (sizeof(informationHeader.width)<4){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }
    if (sizeof(informationHeader.width)<3){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }
    if (sizeof(informationHeader.width)<2){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }

    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.height,sizeof(informationHeader.height));
    if (sizeof(informationHeader.height)<4){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }
    if (sizeof(informationHeader.height)<3){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }
    if (sizeof(informationHeader.height)<2){
        out.write((char*) &informationHeader.padding,1);
        }   

    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.planes,sizeof(informationHeader.planes));
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.bitDepth,sizeof(informationHeader.bitDepth));
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.compression,4);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.imageSize,4);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.xPixelsPerMetre,4);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.yPixelsPerMetre,4);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.colours,4);
    out.write((char*) &informationHeader.importantColours,4);

    //pixel data
    for (int y=0; y < renderSize[1]; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x< renderSize[0]; x++) {
            out.write((char*) &pixelArray[x][y],sizeof(pixel));
        }
    }

    out.close();


}


// end bmp-----------

int main() {

pixel pixelArray[renderSize[0]][renderSize[1]];

    for (int y=0; y < renderSize[1]; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x< renderSize[0]; x++) {
            float rayPos[3] = {x,y, -1000.0};
            float rayDir[3] = {0.0,0.0,-1.0};   
            bool intersect;

            //for each object in scene, see if intersects. (for now there is only one object to make things easier)

            //-------sphere ray intersection....
            float distance[3];
            distance[0]= rayPos[0]-sphere1Pos[0];
            distance[1]= rayPos[1]-sphere1Pos[1];
            distance[2]= rayPos[2]-sphere1Pos[2];
            float a = dot(rayDir, rayDir);
            float b = 2 * dot(rayDir, distance);
            float c = dot(distance, distance) - (sphere1Radius * sphere1Radius);

            float disc = b * b - 4 * a * c;

            if (disc < 0)
                intersect=false;
            else
                intersect=true;


            //--------------------

            if (intersect==true){
                pixelArray[x][y].R = 0;
                pixelArray[x][y].G = 0;
                pixelArray[x][y].B = 0;
                }

            else {
                pixelArray[x][y].R = 0;
                pixelArray[x][y].G = 0;
                pixelArray[x][y].B = 0;
                }



            // trace to lights (as long as another object is not in the way) 

        }

    }
    //write .bmp
    bitmapMagicNumber magicNum;
    bitmapFileHeader fileHeader;
    bitmapInformationHeader informationHeader;

    setBitmapMagicNumber(magicNum);
    setBitmapFileHeader(fileHeader,informationHeader, pixelArray[renderSize[0]][renderSize[1]]);
    setBitmapInformationHeader(informationHeader);

    writeBitmap(magicNum,fileHeader,informationHeader, pixelArray[renderSize[0]][renderSize[1]]);
}

//calculate dot product
float dot(float* a,float* b)
{
float dp = 0.0;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    dp += a[i] * b[i];
return dp;
}
```

Comment: "I'm fairly new to C++ but have been using Python for a while."  C++ is for all practical purposes nothing like Python.  If you don't already have a good C++ book, consider getting one of the introductory C++ books from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I have one and have read it,I just thought my inexperience was worth mentioning as it may be the cause of some of my mistakes.

Comment: @Elephantic:  Great!  I just wanted to be sure.  :-)  A lot of people try to learn without a good book, and it generally doesn't turn out well.

Comment: Don't use `<pre>` or `<code>` - select the code and press the `010` button or indent by at least 4 spaces.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was trying to press the button and then paste the code. Thank you for fixing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may not be your only issue, you almost certainly have [data alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) issues.

In your `bitmapFileHeader`, for example, assuming `long` has four-byte alignment and `short` has two-byte alignment, there will be two bytes of unnamed padding between `magicNumber` and `fileSize` (there are similar issues in most of the other data structures).

As a solution, you can represent the header and other structures as an array of `char` (which has no padding) and copy the relevant data into the correct locations in the array.

Your compiler might provide a way to "pack" the data structures so that they are unaligned, which can also solve your problem, but doing so is wholly unportable.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look in to that. But do you know how to solve my problem when passing the pixel array to setBitmapFileHeader? It's stopping me from compiling the program and I wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: @Elephantic:  `renderSize` needs to be `const` in order to be used as the dimension of an array.  `&pixelArray` yields a pointer to the array, not a pointer to the first element (the pointer values are the same, but their types are different).  If you drop the `&`, it should solve your problem.  Note that you also have an error in your size computation (you use `renderSize[1]` twice) and that accessing a two-dimensional array as if it were a one-dimensional array is technically not allowed.

Comment: Thank you :)
The compile time error though is at the line:

setBitmapFileHeader(fileHeader,informationHeader,pixelArray);

returning: "error: conversion from 'pixel (*)[(((ling unsigned int)(((int)renderSize[1]) - 1)) + 1u)]' to non-scalar type 'pixel' requested"

My problem is that I don't really know what to put for the type here: "void setBitmapFileHeader(bitmapFileHeader& fileHeader,bitmapInformationHeader& informationHeader,pixel pixelArray) {"
I thought it would be pixel, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Elephantic:  It needs to be a `pixel pixelArray[][renderSize[1]`.

Comment: I missed an `]` at the end of that last comment's code.  Oops.

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much but I'm still struggling and I'm not sure what's wrong. Here's a screenshot of the .bmp in a hexadecimal editor: http://yfrog.com/fvpicture1ygp Any clues as to what's wrong?

Comment: @Elephantic:  I'm not really that familiar with the BMP file format, certainly not familiar enough to see what's wrong in a hex dump ;-).  I'd compare your hex dump with a hex dump from a good .bmp file (i.e., one created from Paint or something like that).

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'm almost there now, I just have one strange problem. Everything is correct up to mid way trough the important colours (which I set to 0), where all sorts of random characters spring up and this continues for the next few bytes, a couple of bytes in to the pixel data. Before and after that everything is fine, but I just can't explain it. My current code is in the edit. I've compared it with an good .bmp and it should all be zerod. I can't explain where it's coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've always done output as a .ppm.  the format couldn't be any simpler:

```
FILE * out = fopen("out.ppm", "wb");
fprintf(out, "P6 %d %d 255\n", HEIGHT, WIDTH);

for(int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
  {
    color c = get_pixel_color(i,j)
    putc(c.red, out);
    putc(c.green, out);
    putc(c.blue, out);
  }

fclose(out);
```

...where red, green, and blue are ints, but must take on values between 0 and 255.  The 255 in the ppm header indicates that the max value of a color channel is 255.

Most image editors will read a .ppm: gimp, photoshop, etc.  I've always loved it because I can remember the format off the top of my head and I don't have to write anything that isn't used...  When I REALLY need a .bmp or a .jpg, etc., I use imagemagick convert to convert my ppm to that format.

Comment: In hindsight that's probably what I should have done from the start but I've gone to far to give up now!

Answer (score 1):

[This code](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/bmp/BITMAP.C) have functions for reading/writting BMPs on Windows and some other platform. Take a look.